# Set the channelSection country using the YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a YouTube channel.  Within that channel I have a channelSection called "Brazil".

I want to limit that section so that only people in Brazil can view it.

In the documentation I see how to set the country parameter for a channel, but not a channelSection.

Per documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/update

The only items I can update are:

- snippet.type

  snippet.style

  snippet.title

  snippet.position

  contentDetails.playlists[]

  contentDetails.channels[]

  targeting.countries[]

  targeting.languages[]

  targeting.regions[]

Our YouTube rep wrote to us that "*To set the snippet.country  property for a channel  resource, you actually need to update the brandingSettings.channel.country  property.  This setting does not affect targeting in any way.*"

So I am a bit confused.  Do I set the channel's brandingSettings.channel.country setting to Brazil or the channelSection, and if so, how?

### Update

Following the answer below, I receive the following error:

```
"domain": "global", "reason": "backendError", "message": "Backend Error"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they might've been confused about what you were trying to do. Changing the `brandingSettings.channel` property should only set

> the country with which the channel is associated. [[source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels)]

I believe the correct way to do what you're asking is by adding "Brazil" to the `targeting.regions[]` list.

From the documentation:

> **targeting.countries[]**: A list of [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search/code/)
>   where the channel section is visible. [[source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections)]

Since you've already created the `channelSection`, you'd just use [`channelSections.update()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/update) to provide a `channelSection` resource and specify Brazil for the targeting country. According to the ISO 3166-1 country code list, the code for Brazil is "**BR**". Note that if you are submitting an update request and your request does not specify a value for a property that already has a value, the property's existing value will **be deleted**.

Afterwards, you can use [`channelSections.list()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/list) to check your `channelSection` resource and see that it should only be visible to users in Brazil (`targeting.countries[]` should have "**BR**" as the only value). Or maybe you could use some proxy extension to view the channel section from different countries to see if it's working as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately when I try to update the targeting for countries I keep getting "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
"

Comment: I couldn't find anything about that error on the section for channel sections ([docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#channelsections)), and it doesn't seem like the core errors documentation is very helpful either (["BackendError: A backend error occurred."](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)). Not sure what else you can do besides waiting for a bit and trying again later or perhaps filing a ticket on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).